# Iterate though sequence and then call Count() or create a List by the start and then call Count

Tags: c#

The language I use is `c#`.

Let that we want to iterate through the elements of a sequence called `customers`, which is a sequence of objects of a fictional type called `Customer`. In terms of code, let that we have the following:

```
IEnumerable<Customer> customers = module.GetCustomers();
```

where `module` is an service layer's class through one of it's methods, we can retrieve all the customers. That being sain the iteration through the elements of `customers` would be:

```
foreach(var customer in customers)
{

}
```

Let now that we want after having iterated through the elements of `customers` to get the number of customers. That could be done like below:

```
int numberOfCustomers = customers.Count();
```

My concern/question now is the following:

Using the `Count()` method we iterate again through the elements of `customers`. However, if we had created an in memory collection of this objects, calling for instance the method `ToList()`:

```
List<Customer> customers = module.GetCustomers()
                                 .ToList();
```

we would have the number of customers in `O(1)`,using the `Count` property of the list `customers`.

In order to find out between these two options, which is the best one, I wrote a simple console app and I used the `StopWatch` class to profile them. However, I didn't come in a clear result.

Which of these two options is the best one?

**UPDATE**

I ran the following console app:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEnumerable<int> numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000);

        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        stopwatch.Start();

        foreach (var number in numbers)
            Console.WriteLine(number);


        Console.WriteLine(numbers.Count());

        stopwatch.Stop();

        // I got 175ms
        Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        Console.ReadKey();

        stopwatch.Restart();

        List<int> numbers2 = numbers.ToList();

        foreach (var number in numbers2)
            Console.WriteLine(number);

        Console.WriteLine(numbers2.Count);

        stopwatch.Stop();

        // I got 86ms
        Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        Console.ReadKey();          
    }
}
```

Then I ran this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IEnumerable<int> numbers = Enumerable.Range(0, 1000);

        Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();

        stopwatch.Start();

        List<int> numbers2 = numbers.ToList();

        foreach (var number in numbers2)
            Console.WriteLine(number);

        Console.WriteLine(numbers2.Count);

        stopwatch.Stop();

        // I got 167ms
        Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        Console.ReadKey();

        stopwatch.Restart();

        foreach (var number in numbers)
            Console.WriteLine(number);


        Console.WriteLine(numbers.Count());

        stopwatch.Stop();

        // I got 104ms
        Console.WriteLine(stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);

        Console.ReadKey();          
    }
}
```

Comment: A sequence of objects of type `Customer`. You could imagine that this is the result of a linq query, which usually is a IEnumerable<T>, unless we call explicitly `ToList()` or `ToDictionary()` etc.

Comment: Answer: it depends.  There's also another option you haven't mentioned, which is to declare a counter variable and increment it inside your `foreach` loop.  Then you can kill two birds with one stone, as it were.

Comment: @Christos: a LINQ query could also end with `ToList` and return that as `IEnumerable<T>`. That's why i'm asking. In that case `Enumerable.Count` would use the [`ICollection<T>.Count` property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5s3kzhec(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @phoog I had this thought. However I didn't thought that would be the best one. Certainly, we will avoid to create an in memory collection, if we follow this way.

Comment: @phoog I was about to suggest that, but it is a bit dangerous as you may break your loop prematurely. In fact, you may not do that now, but in two days/weeks/months/years time when editing your code add an `if`-condition with a `break` and suddenly find your count to be wrong. That being said, I think the general rule about micro-optimizations (i.e. don't do them unless you can show that you need them) applies, especially since the test was apparently not so clear as to show it makes a difference.

Comment: @Christos as Tim Schmelter points out, unless you have a specific library in mind, you can't rule out the possibility that `customers` already *is* an in-memory collection.

Comment: @TimSchmelter suppose that returns a pure `IEnumerable<T>`. It is not an in memory collection.

Comment: can you share with us your unclear benchmark results ?

Comment: @Selman22 sure thing. Please give me a few minutes to organize them and I will update my post correspondingly. Thanks for being patient.

Comment: @Christos: `StopWatch` measures only the time. But you should also take into consideration that a new in-memory collection consumes memory which migth be ok or not. So it depends also on how often you need to access the `Count`-property or if you also need that list to add or remove items or access them in a certain order/at specific indices. If not i would use a counter or (for better readability) just `Count()`.

Comment: Is `customers` an Entity Framework or Linq2Sql set?  You need to take care that you are not sending another query to the db.

Comment: @TimSchmelter my question created, while I was refactoring the code of a method. The iteratin `foreach` happens only once and the after it is completed the `Count()` is called.

Comment: @Christos you should try that with bigger numbers than 1000. like 250000

Comment: @Selman22 I tried it with 1000, because even in my case the number of the objects are less than 1000. However, I will give it a go.

Comment: if you have less than 1000 items you shouldn't even care about performance.

Comment: @Selman22 you have a good point. However, I was thinking, which would be the correct one at least instances of the order of a few 1000.

Comment: Could that module usefully maintain some CustomersCount property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I usually prefer to make my repository methods return an `IReadOnlyCollection<>`, which helps callers to know that they can safely iterate it multiple times:

```
IReadOnlyCollection<Customer> customers = module.GetCustomers();
```

If I can't do that, and I know that I'm going to iterate over what I'm given multiple times, I'll typically use .ToList() to make sure I'm dealing with an in-memory collection:

```
var customers = module.GetCustomers().ToList();
```

In cases where customers was already an in-memory collection, this adds a little overhead by creating a list, but it helps to avoid the risk of creating an enormous amount of overhead by doing something like retrieving the data from the database multiple times.

Your benchmark is flawed for a few reasons, but one of the biggest reasons is that it's using `Console.WriteLine()`, which performs an I/O operation. That operation will take far, far longer than iterating the collections and counting the results, combined. In fact, the *variance* in the amount of time spent in `Console.WriteLine()` will outweigh the differences in the code you're testing.

But this actually illustrates my point well--I/O operations take vastly longer than CPU and memory operations, so it's often worthwhile to add `.ToList()`, which will probably add microseconds to the run time, in order to avoid the slightest possibility of adding I/O operations, which can add milliseconds.

Comment: If you don't have access to `IReadOnlyCollection<T>` and are only working with `IEnumerable<T>`'s, a sneeky trick to make sure you are not calling `ToList` on a collection that is already in memory is do `var customers = module.GetCustomers(); customers = customers as ICollection<Customer> ?? customers.ToArray();` This will leave in memory collections alone and convert non in memory ones.